# Find an element in html source code and show alert message if it`s found

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, getelementbyid

What I am trying to do is pretty simple though I can`t figure it out.

So imagine you browsing a particular website and every time you switch to a new page the source code of html is changing.

I want to popup an alert message if a particular element is found on that page, but if the element is not found I keep browsing, and as soon as this element appears on another page it shows an alert again.

So I`ve got something like this:

```
function elementCheck(){      
    if (document.getElementsByName("project_test") {        
        alert("This page is tested");       
    } 
    else {
        //keep browsing until this element is found                       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an Userscript for that, ran by TamperMonkey/GreaseMonkey. You just have to invoke the function you already have in the UserScript and that's it.

If the page you're browsing loads HTML asynchronously, via AJAX(i.e. the source code changes without changing the URL), you need to call your function periodically via `setInterval`.

Comment: I am just struggling with writing this code so it works